# Discord.js music bot - stream issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, discord.js, ytdl

For some reason, my code suddenly doesn't work as intended. It worked just a few weeks ago, yet now it refuses to work. I forgot how I tampered with it, but I'm pretty sure it isn't by much. After joining a voice channel, my bot attempts to create an AudioResource via the stream provided by `ytdl()` function from `ytdl-core`. After that I played the resource in an AudioPlayer and subscribed to it.

...The problem is that while the bot lights up in green(indicating it is speaking), there is no sound. It continues to stay there for what I assume to be the duration of the stream I passed in before leaving. I have reason to believe that there's a problem in this part:

```js
const songQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
let songPlayer = Voice.createAudioPlayer();

const waterMark = song.duration.seconds * 16384;
let source = await ytdl(song.url, {
  filter: 'audioonly',
  type: 'opus',
  highWaterMark: waterMark,
  requestOptions: {
    headers: {
      cookie: process.env.COOKIE
    }
  }
})

let stream = Voice.createAudioResource(source, {
  inputType: Voice.StreamType.Arbitrary
})

try {
  await songPlayer.play(stream);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(songPlayer);
}
```

When I attempted to `pipe()` the results, it did get written as a file. The problem is that when I play it for a few seconds, it goes right to the end. Which led me to believe there might be an issue with the stream... did I mess up by await-ing or not await-ing some line of code?

I know `ytdl` stream is `PassThrough`-- but there seems to be an issue. Is there an alternative, or does the issue lie on discord instead of ytdl?

Comment: `I forgot how I tampered with it, but I'm pretty sure it isn't by much` - even a single character being changed can be a big problem in programming

Comment: Well, I generally left it alone till it suddenly didn't work-- so only after that did I tamper with it

Comment: Did it have an error when it stopped working?

Comment: Not one at all, although I think it solved itself a few days later after this question-- thx for the help regardless!